# Is this sentence okay to wish Mother's Day?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, phrases

I'm going to make a design and I'm writing a copy on it which will be:

On this Mother's day, let's thank her for **(her?)** selfless care **(for us?)**.

*(Not very sure if **care** and **care for** has different meanings. Would like to know if there's any difference)*

Now first doubt is about grammar. That's why I've put optional parts in brackets. Secondly **her** seems a bit redundant to me. So I'm not sure if it is grammatically okay or not.

Another doubt is: Is this sentence okay to show my feelings for my mother? Basically I want to show that my mother has cared **(for?)** me the most in my life. By care I mean:

a) She asks me how are you, have you eaten your food, please let me know whenever you feel sick, don't do this, don't do that because it's bad, take rest you're tired, here's your favorite food and so many other things. I hope you got idea.

Comment: You might want to look up the distinction between "care for" and "care about", and then decide which one best describes what you want to say.

Comment: (1) Aren't Mother's Day wishes usually addressed _to_ one's mother? (2) _Her_ is not redundant. (3) Only you can say whether it expresses your feelings!

Comment: @KateBunting didn't get what you said in (1). Would you please elaborate? Is there something wrong?

Comment: I meant that Iwould expect you to say, "Thank you, Mother, for your selfless care for us".

Comment: @KateBunting thanks for clarifying, but I don't understand what's much difference here then? Let's thank her => Does it somehow mean I'm wishing someone else's mother and excluding my mother?

Please reply. I think you mean this.

Comment: Our British _Mothering Sunday_ (as I prefer to call it) was earlier in the year, but greetings cards etc. always contain good wishes and thanks addressed to the sender's own mother. It seemed  odd to design something telling _other_ people that you thank your mother. But maybe that's what you do in your country.

Comment: Cross-posted on ELL: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/246991/18673